# Using Angular and Highcharts and want to use fromEvent from RxJS for legendItemClick

Tags: angular, highcharts, rxjs

I add series with no data to my Highchart chart which are initial not visible. When clicking on the legend next to the chart, an event is triggered and requests the data for the series and shows the data.

This is basically working with the code from
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick

But I want to use fromEvent from RxJS to listen to the event "legenditemclick". After 3 days of searching and trying things, I surrender and ask the community.

Comment: please share the code, which angular highchart library your using, stackblitz with the issue replicated, will be best!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7s761p?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: The commented code in your stackblitz is very close to working, but you seem to have used a slightly incorrect object path to access the element...

Comment: ... Also the typescript `Series | Point` issue in `allItems[0]`, has to be addressed, see the [docs](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Legend#allItems) - line charts have `Series`, pie charts have `Points`. Unfortunately, the type definitions for `LegendItemObject` are missing the `group` entry, nor do RxJS type definitions allow for an `SVGElement`, so the `as any` solution can't be helped (ideally it should have worked with `as HighCharts.Series`). Here's an [edited version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8pbb3d?file=src%2Fmain.ts) of that stackblitz.

Comment: @kikon could you move this comment as answer? Because the comment is the solution, and I can't mark a comment as solution. Thx

Comment: Thank you @wintlef, but as I remember it, I thought my contribution is not substantial enough to be an answer. If you think it's relevant, feel free to write yourself an answer including stuff from my comment.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you want `fromEvent` specifically, since it's a callback function you can use a subject to mock the same behaviour!

If you do not like this solution, kindly highlight the reason for specifically asking for `fromEvent`, because it sound like a lot of work for something that already has a prebuilt solution!

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';
import { fromEvent, Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<highcharts-chart #chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions">
             </highcharts-chart>`,
  imports: [HighchartsChartModule],
})
export class App {
  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
  @ViewChild('chart') chartRef: any;
  private loadDataSubject: Subject<Highcharts.SeriesLegendItemClickEventObject> =
    new Subject<Highcharts.SeriesLegendItemClickEventObject>();
  private loadDataObservable$: Observable<Highcharts.SeriesLegendItemClickEventObject>;

  constructor() {
    this.loadDataObservable$ = this.loadDataSubject.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.loadDataObservable$.subscribe(
        (event: Highcharts.SeriesLegendItemClickEventObject) => {
          this.loadData();
        }
      )
    );
  }

  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        events: {
          legendItemClick: (
            event: Highcharts.SeriesLegendItemClickEventObject
          ) => {
            this.loadDataSubject.next(event);
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chartRef.chart.addSeries({
      type: 'line',
      name: 'nameTest',
      id: 'idTest',
      data: [],
      visible: false,
    });

    // Subscribe to the legendItemClick event using fromEvent
    // const chart2 = Highcharts.charts[Highcharts.charts.length - 1];
    // const legendItemClick$ = fromEvent(
    //   chart2?.legend?.allItems[0]?.legendGroup?.element,
    //   'click'
    // );
    // legendItemClick$.subscribe(() => {
    //   console.log('Legend item clicked using RxJS');
    // });
  }

  loadData() {
    var temp = this.chartRef.chart.get('idTest');
    temp.setData([10, 20]);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zmh4rj?file=src%2Fmain.ts,angular.json)

Comment: Nice code! But with this approach, a lot of code is needed, which makes it not easy to read - as you also say in some way.
That is the reason why I want to know if it is possible to use fromEvent or similar function, which would result in connecting the event with an observable in one line of code. Maybe there is a trick, which I don't know, maybe this is not possible at all.

Comment: @wintlef Got it! All the best!